# Azure Storage Account (classic) access using only the Account Name?

Tags: azure-storage, azure-cli

I need to use either CLI or PowerShell (ARM) to retrieve the key from an Azure Storage Account (classic). The only challenge here is that I'm given only the storage account name and subscription.

With Get-AzStorageAccount and Get-AzStorageAccountKey, I need to provide the Resource Group, which I don't have. The `az storage account show-connection-string` command only works with ARM resources but not classic storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like this:

```
Get-AzResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.ClassicStorage/StorageAccounts" | Where-Object {
    $_.Name -eq $your_storage_account_name
}
```

to find out that information

Comment: Thanks.  That is an option I can probably use.

Comment: This provides the solution to finding the resource group, but not to finding the account key. See my answer for a complete solution.

Comment: ugh, the person specifically asked how to find the resource group of the storage account. if you actually read the question

Answer (score 0):

I used this script to get the connection string of all classic Storage Accounts in the current subscription:

```
#Requires -Modules Az.Resources, Az.Accounts
$classicAccounts = Get-AzResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.ClassicStorage/StorageAccounts"
$token = (Get-AzAccessToken).Token
foreach ($account in $classicAccounts) {
    $keys = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri "https://management.azure.com$($account.ResourceId)/listKeys?api-version=2016-11-01" -Headers @{"Authorization"="Bearer $token"}
    Write-Host "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=$($account.Name);AccountKey=$($keys.primaryKey);EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
}
```

Azure PS does not support retrieval of the keys from classic Storage Accounts; the REST API needs to be used. See [Azure PowerShell GitHub issue #10329: [Az.Storage] Get-AzStorageAccount can't access classic blob storage accounts.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/10329).

For ARM Storage Accounts, there is the `Get-AzStorageAccountKey` cmdlet. In the older AzureRM package, it used to be called `Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey`. For classic Storage Account, they both give the same error:

> Get-AzStorageAccountKey: The Resource 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/mystorageaccount' under resource group 'Default-Storage-WestEurope' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix